# Chrome extension Service Worker not connecting to port when inactive

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I'm making a Chrome extension, in which I have a service worker, which accesses an IndexedDB. When opening the popup I need to exchange data from the service to the popup and vice versa, I do this by opening a port:
`let port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "popup" });`
When the service worker shows it's active, it works perfectly fine. But when the service worker shows it's inactive, it gives off this error:
`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

I've tried everything, trying to wake it up based events, which didn't work, switching browsers to Chrome to see if it's an issue with Brave, also didn't change anything.
I've tried try catch, still showed error, and didn't work.
Tried to set a timeout to let the service worker wake up, also didn't work.
I also don't want to use a background server, as I heard it was deprecated in manifest V3

Comment: It's probably a bug in ManifestV3. Don't use the service worker at all, just access IndexedDB directly in popup.

Comment: @wOxxOm But the data entered in the InedxedDB comes from a script running on a site, that's why I need the service worker, it facilitates the communication between the two

Comment: The popup script can get this data directly.